# How to get the index of an element without 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that looks kind of like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="contact">
        <h1>Person's name</h1>
        <!-- more stuff goes here -->
        <form method="post" action="myurl">
            <input type="submit" value="go" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <h1>Another name</h1>
        <!-- more stuff goes here -->
        <form method="post" action="myOtherUrl">
            <input type="submit" value="go" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery to capture the form's `submit` event and need to get the index of the `div` containing the button that submitted it. Normally I'd use jQuery's [`index()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index) function like so:

```
var i = $(this).parents('.contact').index(this);
```

Unfortunately, the `this` operator in this case refers to the `form` that is being submitted. I think there's probably something simple I'm missing, but my mind's drawing a blank on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
var parent = $(this).closest('div.contact'); // get containing DIV
var i = $('div.contact').index(parent); // get index relative to the rest
```

Comment: I'll just quote myself: "I think there's probably something simple I'm missing..."

Thanks.

Comment: No sweat. I know what its like to be too close to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = $(this).parents('.contact:first').prevAll('.contract').length
```